# Paginate result set having written the query with prepared statements,

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been using paginating classes when I did before the query the traditional way, but now that I have come to do the queries using prepared statements, via the $stmt->fetch() statement, I don't know how to paginate now. I have been looking around and checking the stackoverflow literature and it seems that there is some kind of ready solution for it, some commands or some : sort-> stuff.

How do you paginate what comes out of this loop?  Are there some commands within the "world of prepared statements"? any link, page or web where that is shown?

```
while( $stmt->fetch() )
    {
        printf("%s%s%s%s", $Email, $Webpage, $Telephone, $Mobile);
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414229/convert-mysqli-pagination-to-prepared-statement-pagination

thatnks, your answer solved my problem =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Method 1: `get_result()`:

*Note: This method only works with PHP >= 5.3, having the mysqlnd native driver.

Assuming this was done with MySQLi and you have bound these variables as result vars via `bind_result()`, I would instead use [`get_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) to transfer it into a MySQLi result resource, and fetch the rows as arrays onto an array containing all rows.  Then use any pagination method or plugin you would normally use on array data:

```
// Don't use bind_result()...
// execute your statement
$stmt->execute();
// Get result set into a MySQLi result resource
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// array to hold all results
$rowset = array();
// And fetch with a while loop
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $rowset[] = $row;
}
```

var_dump($rowset);

Now use `$rowset` as a 2D array, with which you can use any pagination method that operates on regular arrays.

#### Method 2: build an array with bound output vars

If you don't have the mysqlnd native driver (and hence cannot use `get_result()`, continue using `bind_result()` but append all of those onto an array:

```
// array to hold all rows
$rowset = array();

// All results bound to output vars
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  // Append an array containing your result vars onto the rowset array
  $rowset[] = array(
    'email' => $Email,
    'webpage' => $Webpage,
    'telephone' => $Telephone,
    'moblile' => $Mobile
  );
}
var_dump($rowset);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will study this and see if I manage it. Thank you both. Yes, I have 5.3.8 and I used MySQLi