# php: Non-object error - array output to table - Prepared Statements pre PHP 5.3

Tags: php, mysql

Non-object error
Error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

My Code:

```
 if($stmt = $dbc->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $search_term);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($bookid, $title, $author, $genre, $isbn, $url);

echo '<table><tr>
<th><a href="browse.php?sort=bi">ID</th>
<th><a href="browse.php?sort=t">Title</a></th>
<th><a href="browse.php?sort=a">Author</th>
<th><a href="browse.php?sort=g">Genre</th>
<th>ISBN</th>
<th>URL</th>
</tr>';


 // array to hold all rows 
    $rowset = array(); 

   // All results bound to output vars 
   while ($stmt->fetch()) { 
       // Append an array containing your result vars onto the rowset array 
            $rowset[] = array( 
            'bookid' => $bookid, 
            'title' => $title, 
            'author' => $author, 
           'genre' => $genre,
          'isbn' => $isbn,
          'url' => $url 
           );
    } // End Fetch

    $size = count($rowset);

    for ($i=0; $i <$size; $i++){
            $row = $rowset->fetch_assoc();  // Error is on this line
```

I am new to prepared statements but that part is working.  I read:
[Paginate result set having written the query with prepared statements,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806038/paginate-result-set-having-written-the-query-with-prepared-statements).

Because my server has PHP 5.2.17, I cannot use get_result().  So I have built an array as the article says.  I can var_dump it (so the query has results) but I want to output into a table.  I have tried different ways to ouput the query and everything seems to come back to this non-object error.  Searching the web, I am getting confused because the OOP articles get into topics more advanced than I can do at the moment.  So I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance for any help you may give.

Comment: What do you think `fetch_assoc()` is supposed to do?

Comment: Or, to rephrase, what are you trying to do in the loop containing `fetch_assoc()`?

Answer (score 2):

The error message says it all. `$rowset` is not an object and therefore has no member function named `fetch_assoc()`.

This code sets `$rowset` to an array of associative arrays.

```
$rowset = array(); 

// All results bound to output vars 
while ($stmt->fetch()) { 
   // Append an array containing your result vars onto the rowset array 
        $rowset[] = array( 
        'bookid' => $bookid, 
        'title' => $title, 
        'author' => $author, 
       'genre' => $genre,
      'isbn' => $isbn,
      'url' => $url 
       );
} // End Fetch
```

`fetch_assoc()` is a member function of a `mysqli_result` object. ([Documenation here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).)

Since you already have your data stored in an array (`$rowset`), you can iterate through each index using a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($rowset as $row) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you build the variable $rowset:

```
$rowset[] = array(...);
```

It is of type **array**. The fetch_assoc() method is part of a MySqli or PDO result object returned from the database.

To accomplish what you are trying to do, try this:

```
foreach($rowset as $row)
{
   // Do something with $row
}
```