# Convert mysqli pagination to prepared statement pagination

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pagination

the current working code with mysqli is as below. I would like to convert it to prepared statements. there is basically three sql query need to convert to prepared statement. the first part is the hardest part for me to figure out the prepared way to get count value which i kinda managed to figure it out eventually.

```
<?php
// Script and tutorial written by Adam Khoury @ developphp.com
// Line by line explanation : youtube.com/watch?v=T2QFNu_mivw
include_once("storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php");
// This first query is just to get the total count of rows
$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products ";
$query2 = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sql2);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query2);
// Here we have the total row count
$rows = $row[0];
// This is the number of results we want displayed per page
$page_rows = 10;
// This tells us the page number of our last page
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
// This makes sure $last cannot be less than 1
if($last < 1){
    $last = 1;
}
// Establish the $pagenum variable
$pagenum = 1;
// Get pagenum from URL vars if it is present, else it is = 1
if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
    $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
}
// This makes sure the page number isn't below 1, or more than our $last page
if ($pagenum < 1) { 
    $pagenum = 1; 
} else if ($pagenum > $last) { 
    $pagenum = $last; 
}
// This sets the range of rows to query for the chosen $pagenum
$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;
// This is your query again, it is for grabbing just one page worth of rows by applying $limit
$sql = "SELECT id,product_name, price FROM products ORDER BY product_name DESC $limit";
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sql);
// This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages
$textline1 = "Products (<b>$rows</b>)";
$textline2 = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>";
// Establish the $paginationCtrls variable
$paginationCtrls = '';
// If there is more than 1 page worth of results
if($last != 1){
    /* First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to 
       the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we
       generate links to the first page, and to the previous page. */
    if ($pagenum > 1) {
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
        // Render clickable number links that should appear on the left of the target page number
        for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0){
                $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
            }
        }
    }
    // Render the target page number, but without it being a link
    $paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';
    // Render clickable number links that should appear on the right of the target page number
    for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
        if($i >= $pagenum+4){
            break;
        }
    }
    // This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the "Next"
    if ($pagenum != $last) {
        $next = $pagenum + 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a> ';
    }
}


$dynamicList = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $id = $row["id"];
    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    $price = $row["price"];
    $dynamicList .= "
                <li><div class='product'>
                <a href='product.php?id=$id' class='info'>
                <span class='holder'>
                <img src='inventory_images/$id.jpg' alt='$product_name' />
                <span class='book-name'>$product_name</span>
                </a>
                 <a href='product.php?id=$id' class='buy-btn'>RM<span class='price'>$price</span></a>
                </div>
                </li>

              ";
}
// Close your database connection
mysqli_close($myConnection);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{ font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
div#pagination_controls{font-size:21px;}
div#pagination_controls > a{ color:#06F; }
div#pagination_controls > a:visited{ color:#06F; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <h2><?php echo $textline1; ?> Paged</h2>
  <p><?php echo $textline2; ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $dynamicList; ?></p>
  <div id="pagination_controls"><?php echo $paginationCtrls; ?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stmt=$myConnection->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products');
// Don't use bind_result()...
// execute your statement
$stmt->execute();
// Get result set into a MySQLi result resource
$result = $stmt->bind_result($id);

// array to hold all rows
$rows = array();

// All results bound to output vars
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  // Append an array containing your result vars onto the rowset array
  $rows[] = array(
    'id' => $id
  );
}
  $rows=$id;
```

for the first part. i think you have got it

Comment: why while and array here?

Comment: i actually was just trying to retrieve the Count number..any better way to get this value?

Answer (score 1):

this answer has been solved by using [Paginate result set having written the query with prepared statements,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806038/paginate-result-set-having-written-the-query-with-prepared-statements?lq=1) method 2.

the full code for reference as below. Thanks

```
<?php
// Script and tutorial written by Adam Khoury @ developphp.com
// Line by line explanation : youtube.com/watch?v=T2QFNu_mivw
include_once("storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php");
// This first query is just to get the total count of rows
$stmt=$myConnection->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products');
// Don't use bind_result()...
// execute your statement
$stmt->execute();
// Get result set into a MySQLi result resource
$result = $stmt->bind_result($id);

// array to hold all rows
$rows = array();

// All results bound to output vars
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  // Append an array containing your result vars onto the rowset array
  $rows[] = array(
    'id' => $id
  );
}
  $rows=$id;


// This is the number of results we want displayed per page
$page_rows = 10;
// This tells us the page number of our last page
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
// This makes sure $last cannot be less than 1
if($last < 1){
    $last = 1;
}
// Establish the $pagenum variable
$pagenum = 1;
// Get pagenum from URL vars if it is present, else it is = 1
if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
    $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
}
// This makes sure the page number isn't below 1, or more than our $last page
if ($pagenum < 1) { 
    $pagenum = 1; 
} else if ($pagenum > $last) { 
    $pagenum = $last; 
}
$dynamicList = "";
$stmt = $myConnection->prepare('SELECT id,product_name,price FROM products ORDER BY product_name LIMIT ?,? ');
$begin= ($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows;
$end= $page_rows;
$stmt->bind_param('ii',$begin,$end);
$stmt->execute();
        /* store result */
        $stmt->store_result();
        /* get the row count */
        $count = $stmt->num_rows;
        if ($count >= 1) {
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $product_name, $price);
// This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages
$textline1 = "Products (<b>$rows</b>)";
$textline2 = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>";
// Establish the $paginationCtrls variable
$paginationCtrls = '';
// If there is more than 1 page worth of results
if($last != 1){
    /* First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to 
       the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we
       generate links to the first page, and to the previous page. */
    if ($pagenum > 1) {
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
        // Render clickable number links that should appear on the left of the target page number
        for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0){
                $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
            }
        }
    }
    // Render the target page number, but without it being a link
    $paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';
    // Render clickable number links that should appear on the right of the target page number
    for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
        if($i >= $pagenum+4){
            break;
        }
    }
    // This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the "Next"
    if ($pagenum != $last) {
        $next = $pagenum + 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a> ';
    }
}


while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                "$id, $product_name, $price,";
                $dynamicList .= "
                <li><div class='product'>
                <a href='product.php?id=$id' class='info'>
                <span class='holder'>
                <img src='inventory_images/$id.jpg' alt='$product_name' />
                <span class='book-name'>$product_name</span>
                </a>
                 <a href='product.php?id=$id' class='buy-btn'>RM<span class='price'>$price</span></a>
                </div>
                </li>

              ";
}
    }
// Close your database connection
mysqli_close($myConnection);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{ font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
div#pagination_controls{font-size:21px;}
div#pagination_controls > a{ color:#06F; }
div#pagination_controls > a:visited{ color:#06F; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <h2><?php echo $textline1; ?> Paged</h2>
  <p><?php echo $textline2; ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $dynamicList; ?></p>
  <div id="pagination_controls"><?php echo $paginationCtrls; ?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try and put the error reporting and see if you have error on mysqli statements:

```
$stmt=$myConnection->prepare('SELECT id FROM products');

// due to syntax error or other reasons may be like privileges prepare can fail so
if ( false===$stmt ) 
{
  // hope you will use better than die to handle but here's only example.
  die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($myConnection->error));
}

$ExecuteStmt = $stmt->execute();
// execute() can also fail for various reasons.
if ( false===$ExecuteStmt ) 
{
  //again same thing about die();
  die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($myConnection->error));
}

$myConnection->close();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i got this array array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> int(50) } }, how do i extract that 50 number?